# Source control on C# DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, synchronization

I've just started using a DataSet at work
and source control is a nightmare i.e. using a sync tool/source comparer to sync the source code to the server. As there are about 4 developers that would be modifying the dataset, the syncing could get quite tricky. Has anyone got any ideas or opinions on this?

We currently use data access classes etc. which makes life easier as changes in code can be easily seen and synced. As with the dataset, its code is auto generated. and if more than one person is modifying it, it's quite hard to merge the changes...any ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand how source control and datasets go together?

Comment: @giddy - they go together like China and Human Rights or Israel and Palestine. (Sorry, forgot which stackexchange site I was on there for a moment)

Comment: @giddy: Like peanut butter and petroleum jelly. Seriously, though, he's probably talking about the generated code for strongly-typed datasets in .NET. As with most designer-generated code in .NET, trying to merge conflicting updates in generated code is perilous at best, and a fool's errand at worst.

Comment: David loL!  @Xai its very unclear what you are doing, are you doing your own source control with a dataset? (this would be scary) or are you just talking about data synchronization when it comes to data sets?

Comment: @adam oh I see. That could be it.

Comment: Yes I meant the auto generated source code files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with an ORM as well, and our approach is to designate a single person as being responsible for doing all code generation.  When a developer needs to modify the schema, they have to contact the "ORM Master", who applies the schema changes to a clean, "canonical" copy of the database, then re-runs the generation tool, and checks in the new code.  The person who requested the change then gets latest and is up and running, and the build doesn't get broken.

While this adds something of a bottleneck, in practice it has not been a problem, and it avoids issues where two or more developers make different schema changes that add conflicts, etc., causing a knot of problems to sort out.

I hope this addresses the question you are asking, this is how I interpret your question, in any case.

Comment: +1; this is what I've found to be the best option (well, really, the *only* viable option) when dealing with designer-generated code.

Comment: Thanks Guy, I was thinking along the lines of this approach. Greatly appreciated!